# Service vs Function in OSI model

Tags: networking, tcp, ip, osi

I have a hard time understanding the difference between a service and a function of a layer in the OSI reference model. For instance is multiplexing/demultiplexing a service or a function of the transport layer and why?

Comment: Which do *you* hypothesize it is? Justify your answer. (If nothing else this will likely make for better responses.)

Comment: I have read the definition of session multiplexing/demultiplexing on wikipedia. I don't have a real thought on that.

Comment: The OSI model is just a model, and nothing in the real world follows it. The IP Services model is what was used for OSes, but it, too, is just a model, albeit much closer to what you find in the real world.

Answer (score 0):

A *service* has a function.  A *service* is functionality available to an outside context; in the OSI case, services may be used by other layers. In the OSI context, services are synonymous with *cross-layer function*.

With layering, typically cross-layer usage (reference) is one-way ("down") and only with adjacent layers.

See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model#Cross-layer_functions